# Distinguish rock scences using opencv

Tags: opencv

I am struggling with finding the appropriate contour algorithm for a low quality image. The example image shows a rock scene:

[image]
[image]

What I am trying to achieve is to find contours arround features such as:

- light areas
- dark areas
- grey1 areas
- grey2 areas
- etc. until grey-n areas

(The number of areas shall be a parameter of choice)

I do not want to take a simple binary-threshold but rather use some sort of contour-finding (for example watershed or other). The major feature-lines shall be kept, noise within a feature-are can be flattened.

The result of my code can be seen on the images to the right.

Unfortunately, as you can easily tell, the colors do not really represent the original large-scale image features! For example: check out the two areas that I circled with red - these features are almost completely flooded with another color. What I imagine is that at least the very light and the very dark areas are covered by its own color.

```
cv::Mat cv_src = cv::imread(argv[1]);
cv::Mat output;
cv::Mat cv_src_gray;

cv::cvtColor(cv_src, cv_src_gray, cv::COLOR_RGB2GRAY);

double clipLimit = 0.1;
cv::Size titleGridSize = cv::Size(8,8);
cv::Ptr<cv::CLAHE> clahe = cv::createCLAHE(clipLimit, titleGridSize);
clahe->apply(cv_src_gray, output);

cv::equalizeHist(output, output);

cv::cvtColor(output, cv_src, cv::COLOR_GRAY2RGB);
// Create binary image from source image
cv::Mat bw;
cv::cvtColor(cv_src, bw, cv::COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
cv::threshold(bw, bw, 180, 255, cv::THRESH_BINARY);

// Perform the distance transform algorithm
cv::Mat dist;
cv::distanceTransform(bw, dist, cv::DIST_L2, CV_32F);

// Normalize the distance image for range = {0.0, 1.0}
cv::normalize(dist, dist, 0, 1., cv::NORM_MINMAX);

// Threshold to obtain the peaks
cv::threshold(dist, dist, .2, 1., cv::THRESH_BINARY);

// Create the CV_8U version of the distance image
cv::Mat dist_8u;
dist.convertTo(dist_8u, CV_8U);

// Find total markers
std::vector<std::vector<cv::Point> > contours;
cv::findContours(dist_8u, contours, cv::RETR_EXTERNAL, cv::CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);
int ncomp = contours.size();

// Create the marker image for the watershed algorithm
cv::Mat markers = cv::Mat::zeros(dist.size(), CV_32S);

// Draw the foreground markers
for (int i = 0; i < ncomp; i++)
    cv::drawContours(markers, contours, i, cv::Scalar::all(i+1), -1);

// Draw the background marker
cv::circle(markers, cv::Point(5,5), 3, CV_RGB(255,255,255), -1);

// Perform the watershed algorithm

cv::watershed(cv_src, markers);

// Generate random colors
std::vector<cv::Vec3b> colors;
for (int i = 0; i < ncomp; i++)
{
    int b = cv::theRNG().uniform(0, 255);
    int g = cv::theRNG().uniform(0, 255);
    int r = cv::theRNG().uniform(0, 255);

    colors.push_back(cv::Vec3b((uchar)b, (uchar)g, (uchar)r));
}

// Create the result image
cv::Mat dst = cv::Mat::zeros(markers.size(), CV_8UC3);

// Fill labeled objects with random colors
for (int i = 0; i < markers.rows; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < markers.cols; j++)
    {
        int index = markers.at<int>(i,j);
        if (index > 0 && index <= ncomp)
            dst.at<cv::Vec3b>(i,j) = colors[index-1];
        else
            dst.at<cv::Vec3b>(i,j) = cv::Vec3b(0,0,0);
    }
}

// Show me what you got
imshow("final_result", dst);
```

Comment: I would consider using canny algorithm before extracting contours and i would consider using erosion and dilation or mayber some law pass filter in order to increase the contrast between the photo's colors

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can use a simple clustering such as k-means for this, then examine the cluster centers (or the mean and standard deviations of each cluster). I quickly tried it in matlab.

```
im = imread('tvBqt.jpg');
gr = rgb2gray(im);

x = double(gr(:));
idx = kmeans(x, 4);
cl = reshape(idx, 600, 472);

figure,
subplot(1, 2, 1), imshow(gr, []), title('original')
subplot(1, 2, 2), imshow(label2rgb(cl), []), title('clustered')
```

The result:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You could try using SLIC Superpixels. I tried it and showed some good results. You could vary the parameters to get better clustering.

- [SLIC Superpixels](http://ivrg.epfl.ch/research/superpixels)
- [SLIC Superpixels with OpenCV C++](https://github.com/PSMM/SLIC-Superpixels)
- [SLIC Superpixels with OpenCV Python](https://github.com/jayrambhia/superpixels-SLIC)

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for the SLIC Sperpixel idea ! However since I try to establish contours arround areas-of-the-same-color (or grey-level in this case), the SLIC-idea does not seem to me the right thing...

Comment: what do you mean by that? Did you try changing parameters? It might give better results. There is also SLICO which doesn't require any parameters.

Comment: I guess I did not fully understand how to deduct (for example 5) greylevel colors and its resulting closed countours arround out of such superpixels. I am sure one finds the appropriate parameters in order to lay the big pixels along greylevels. But again, I eventually need the  entire contour arround one greylevel (and not several big-pixel-split countours of the same greylevel...).